# can't boot windows 7 after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-7

I want to install Ubuntu alongside window 7. but the dual-booting is not working. I will describe the moves I made.

1. I Installed Ubuntu, the Ubuntu boot loader was probably written in /sda where my windows 7 was installed.Then I can boot Ubuntu, but can't boot windows 7. However I have 2 windows 7 loader options on the grub2. interface.
2. Then somebody tried to fix it for me, I don't know what he did, but I can't boot either of the systems this time.
3. I erased disk c: including the system reserve partition and restored win7. Then I can't boot windows I thought it might has something to do with the system reserve partiton and UEFI booting staff. I generated the partition and  used bcdboot to recover it.Then win 7 is working this time
4. I think maybe I wrote the ubuntu loader in the wrong place. so I tried to write it in '/boot ' or just in the root '/', but I don't have the dual boot option at all. It goes straight to windows 7.
5. I write ubuntu boot loader again to c:/ also sda. Then I get back to the situation just as the very beginning. but this time I have only 1 windows 7  loader which is not working.
6. I tried to use boot-repair to fix it. unfortunately it gives me this:
   ' The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session. This will enable this feature. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode.'
   http://paste.ubuntu.com/24339981/

Sorry I don't fully understand the problem but was so obsessed to have it settled. So I wasted 2 days on googling and trying anything seeming reaonable . Now I know that it's not worthy to move aimlessly and I am putting it aside. Hope someone could help me out . Really appreciate it .

Comment: Ad 6: Change your BIOS to boot in UEFI mode and run boot-repair again.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is very strange, probably because of actions taken in step #2 that you don't know about. In brief:

- Your disk uses the [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning scheme.
- The MBR contains GRUB code, indicating a setup of Ubuntu to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.
- Your `/dev/sda2` is a FAT partition of a size that's common for an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and it contains Windows EFI/UEFI-mode boot loader files. This is consistent with an EFI-mode boot, but such a partition is normally found on [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) disks, not MBR disks. (MBR and GPT are more-or-less mutually exclusive; although a combination called a "hybrid MBR" is possible, this is an ugly and dangerous hack that's mostly used on Macs.)

My suspicion is that your computer was originally installed to boot Windows in EFI mode from a GPT disk, but in step #1, you installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. (Installing one OS in EFI mode and the other in BIOS mode is awkward at best, and usually results in problems.) Then, whoever did your step #2, not understanding the setup or how best to fix it, converted the disk from GPT to MBR and tried to get it to boot Windows in BIOS mode, but failed. Although your subsequent efforts *might* have worked, for whatever reason they didn't, leaving you worse off than when you began.

My first suggestion is to read my [Web page on the CSM.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) A failure to understand the issues described on that page is likely what got you into your current predicament, and a successful recovery is dependent on either your understanding those issues or good luck. Either your CSM was enabled at the start or you enabled it to install Ubuntu, and this was a mistake, because the CSM complicates the boot path and makes possible a configuration in which one OS is installed in EFI mode and the other is installed in BIOS mode. As noted above, such a configuration is awkward to control and creates new pitfalls. Thus, I recommend you disable the CSM before doing anything else. How you do this varies from one computer to another, so I can't present specific instructions on this; you'll just have to poke around in your firmware setup tool until you find an option relating to the CSM, BIOS-mode booting, legacy-mode booting, or UEFI-mode booting and set it appropriately.

With the CSM disabled, you have two basic options:

- **Re-install everything** -- This is likely to be the easiest approach. You should delete all the disk's partitions, convert the disk from MBR to GPT form, re-install Windows, and finally re-install Ubuntu. As noted on my CSM page, referenced earlier, you may need to take care to create EFI-bootable installation media for both Windows and Ubuntu. (See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/05/31/installing-windows-7-on-uefi-based-computer/) for instructions on installing Windows 7 in EFI mode.)
- **Repair what you've got** -- In theory, you can repair the current configuration to boot in EFI mode. This will require converting from MBR to GPT in a *non-destructive* way (you can use my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)) tool to do this -- it comes with Ubuntu). With that done, you can run Boot Repair *from an EFI-mode boot;* or use my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB drive or CD-R to boot once and then install rEFInd's Debian package or PPA. With any luck your current Windows boot loader will then work well enough to boot Windows; but if not, you may need to repair it. Perhaps you could use part of [this procedure](https://web.archive.org/web/20170306032145/http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt/) to do the job, or you might have to ask on a Windows forum for detailed instructions.

An alternative would be to leave the computer's CSM enabled and try to get it booting in BIOS mode. Since GRUB is starting already, Boot Repair won't really help, at least not initially; you must install a BIOS-mode version of the Windows boot loader -- but I'm not an expert on Windows recovery, so you may need to ask on a Windows forum about that. Also, installing a BIOS-mode Windows boot loader is likely to partially wipe out GRUB, necessitating re-installing it -- which is most easily done with Boot Repair, which you say is thinking it must boot in EFI mode. My suspicion is that this is because it's seeing `/dev/sda2` and interpreting it as an ESP. If so, deleting that partition might help; but of course if you get this far, you'll have a working Windows, and there's a slim chance that deleting `/dev/sda2` might make it fail. Thus, in addition to the usual CSM pitfalls, this procedure runs the risk of creating new problems once you fix one of your current ones -- or maybe even creating new problems while *not* fixing the current one.